# What should I do if a question is answered via email?

Tags: support, answers

I recently asked [System upgrade for a small home-server?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/894/system-upgrade-for-a-small-home-server) , and someone answered the question via email:

[image]

Obviously the question should be answered as an answer on the question itself, ***not*** via email, as:

- This means that if someone else has the same question, there is no answer;
- Defeats the reputation system (e.g, no rep for answering or accepting);
- Means the question itself may go unanswered

I responded to the email by requesting the question be answered an an answer on the question itself:

[image]

Did I take the correct action?
What about if they do not answer the question using the 'answer' facility? Should I self-answer the question, using the details they supplied in their email?

Comment: You did the best you could do.

Comment: If he do not take any action, then Andy's answer is a way to go.

Comment: Aye, take Andy's solution. You can also send one back encouraging him to answer the post. This is one of the problems with leaving your email address in your profile!

Comment: @ArtOfCode True, but I leave my address in my profile due to offering private programming help. It's not my main email address (in fact it just redirects and doesn't actually exist [i.e, there's no mailbox attached to it]).

Comment: Ah, that helps. Well, if you're not opposed to the odd email like this, an anonymised email can well be a good thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they don't answer the question in a reasonable period of time<sup>*</sup>, I'd post what they sent you as a community wiki answer, if you feel it answers your question. You should also expand on the answer at little, as there aren't a lot of details *why* it answers your question. There may be snippets of information behind those links that helped convince you that this is a good answer.

---

<sup>*</sup> In this case, you get to decide what "reasonable" means